# comportamiento de reverse_iterator con const char[]

Tags: c++, iteradores

Teniendo los siguientes objetos:

```
const char      a[]{"abcdefghij"}; // Arreglo de caracteres (longitud 11)
const std::string s{"abcdefghij"}; // basic_string<char> estandar
```

Esperaba que estos bucles se comportaran igual:

```
// 1) Muestra NADA, esperaba "jihgfedcba"
for (auto begin = std::rbegin(a), end = std::rend(a); begin != end; ++begin)
    std::cout << *begin;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

```
// 2) Muestra "jihgfedcba", tal y como esperaba
for (auto begin = std::rbegin(s), end = std::rend(s); begin != end; ++begin)
    std::cout << *begin;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Pero al mostrar el arreglo de caracteres no muestra nada mientras que mostrar el `string` muestra la salida esperada.

El mostrar el arreglo de caracteres también afecta en cómo se muestra el `string`: si el bucle 1 se escribe antes del bucle 2 el programa no muestra nada pero escribiendo el bucle 2 antes que el uno muestra un solo `jihgfedcba`.

---

He podido observar que modificando el valor de retorno de `std::rbegin(a)` soluciona el problema:

```
// Muestra "jihgfedcba", tal y como esperaba
// notese el ++!!
for (auto begin = ++std::rbegin(a), end = std::rend(a); begin != end; ++begin)
    std::cout << *begin;
std::cout << std::endl;

// Muestra "jihgfedcba", tal y como esperaba
for (auto begin = std::rbegin(s), end = std::rend(s); begin != end; ++begin)
    std::cout << *begin;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

---

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char      a[]{"abcdefghij"};
```

Realmente se convierte en

```
const char      a[]{ 'a','b',...,'i','j','\0'};
```

Si llamas a `std::rbegin`, lo que hace es apuntar al carácter '\0'. Lo que puede suceder con esto (que ya depende más del entorno de la consola) es que el bien no se imprima nada o, como es mi caso, imprima un espacio antes de empezar con la secuencia esperada.

¿Por qué este comportamiento? Básicamente porque realmente char* no impone restricciones sobre qué es lo que va a almacenar. No tienes por qué hacer que la cadena termine con '\0' (esto únicamente es necesario si vas a hacer uso de las funciones de manipulación de cadenas de la librería estándar).

Otra posible solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
const char      a[]{ 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i' };
```

De esta forma evitas que el compilador añada el caracter nulo al final de la secuencia, por lo que podrás evitar ese preincremento inicial.

Comment: El tipo de retorno de `std::rbegin(a)` es `reverse_iterator<const char *>`, entiendo que `std::rbegin` devuelva un iterador apuntando a `\0` lo que no entiendo es por qué **sin** ajustar el retorno de `std::rbegin(a)` no muestra la cadena.

Comment: Como te digo, tiene pinta de que eso es comportamiento de tu consola, en mi caso me imprime un espacio al inicio

Comment: Parece el comportamiento de la consola de [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k1RqUEKvVRxedJVf), tanto para gcc como para clang.

Comment: Si su comportamiento es detectar el '\0' como fin de secuencia... puede que descarte el resto de caracteres hasta que se encuentre con un salto de línea.

Comment: Si te fijas, tras el bucle hay un `std::endl`, que añade un salto de línea y *flushea* el stream :O

Comment: Sí, pero está después del bucle... mete el salto de línea dentro del bucle

Comment: `for (auto begin = std::rbegin(a), end = std::rend(a); begin != end; ++begin)
        std::cout << *begin << std::endl;` Se comporta igual que sin el `std::endl` dentro del bucle.

Comment: Me temo que tendrás que preguntar en el foro de Wandbox